# Reload div content and sort the table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sorttable.js

I can reload the div contents using ajax but unable to sort the table contents. `sorttable.js` is not working after reloading the div using ajax.

I have wasted lot of time finding solution for this. Please can any one suggest how  can I reload the div content and sort the table.

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
        document.getElementById('displayarea').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('AutoRefreshValid()',75*1000); // JavaScript function calls AutoRefresh() every 75 seconds 
    } 
} 

xmlHttp.open("GET","RPT_STATUS_AJAX_DIV_REAL_ADMIN.jsp?order=<%=strOrder%>&Order‌​By=<%=strOrderBy%>",true); 

xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: please give the details of your code..

Comment: xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
                        document.getElementById('displayarea').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                        setTimeout('AutoRefreshValid()',75*1000); // JavaScript function calls AutoRefresh() every 75 seconds
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.open("GET","RPT_STATUS_AJAX_DIV_REAL_ADMIN.jsp?order=<%=strOrder%>&OrderBy=<%=strOrderBy%>",true);
                xmlHttp.send(null);

Comment: use simple js and ajax function in sted of this

Answer (score 0):

Please recall your sortable function when your ajax call completes. A simple prototype is given below.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your_url',
  success:function(resp) {
    // put content in div

    $('element').sortable();
  }
});
```

Comment: Shayan can you please explain title more how to call and where to call. Even i need to fix the table header also.